# How do I calculate residential fruit spray application rate for commercial spray?

Tags: fruit-trees, pesticide

I have over a dozen fruit trees I raise as a hobby.  I recently purchased some [Horticultural Oil](http://www.domyownpestcontrol.com/ultrapure-oil-horticultural-insecticide-miticide-and-fungicide-p-2363.html) to apply this spring.  The [label](http://www.domyownpestcontrol.com/msds/Ultra%20Pure%20Oil.pdf) states the following commercial application rate:

> **DORMANT OR DELAYED DORMANT:**
>   Use 1-2 gallons per 100 gallons of water at 100-800 gallons per acre.
>   (Concentrate Spray: Use 3-8 gallons per
>   acre in a minimum of 20-100 gallons of water per acre.)

How do I calculate how much to apply using my small pull behind garden sprayer?  I would probably only mix up 25 gallons of water at most and 3 gallons of concentrate seems like too much!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you're using 25 gallons of water, you are using only 25% the amount of water on the mixing instructions, so use only 25% the amount of concentrate, around 1-2 quarts.

Application rate is 100-800 gallons of mix per acre, but with only a dozen or so trees you're looking at significantly less than an acre. Figure out how much of an acre you're working with and do the same math for how much mixed spray to use.

Comment: Thanks for the response! This may seem like a stupid question, but how do you calculate "how much of an acre"?  Am I roughly calculating the square footage each tree takes up and adding them all together?

Comment: Yes, or if they're close enough together calculate the area the entire orchard covers.

Answer (score 3):

Your question gives the answer. It says use either a 1-2% mix, or up to 8%.